# SQL Server 2017 Cross Apply odd behavior

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

We recently upgraded to SQL Server 2017 from I believe it was 2010ish. I have a report I generate for a client that is now giving me an error and was hoping somebody has seen this or can provide some clarification.

Basically I have a table that has orders, I have another table that stores additional information for the orders such as billing charges, notes, just any random data we decide to hang off it. The second table has an ID that matches the ID of the order, a kind and a value. The value is a string field so we can accommodate any type of data we want to store.

The basic query is as follows:

```
select col1, col2, charges 
from table1
cross apply 
     (select sum(parse(stringfield) as money) as charges 
      from table2 
      where orderid = table1.id and kind = 'billingcharge') as charges
```

This is throwing me an error of invalid money format converting 'some long note text'. I searched the table for that 'some long note text' and found it with a kind of 'ordernotes', it does not have a kind of 'billingcharge'. I ran another query to get all records with a kind of 'billingcharge' and they are all valid numbers like 50.00. It appears as though it's applying the parse before actually limiting the records.  To make this even more strange, I know there's roughly 2000 orders being returned in this query. So I changed it to "select top 4000 col1, col2, charges" and then the query runs without issue.

Has anybody run into this issue and have any guidance? Thank you.

Comment: You should use `TRY_PARSE`/`TRY_CONVERT` - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors

Comment: I did TRY_PARSE and received the same result basically, string or binary data would be truncated.  I can find another way to compile the data I'm sure, it just seems very odd to be that this newer version of SQL would be trying to convert data on a row that is not selected per the where clause.

Comment: This isn't a new issue.It has always been query plan  dependent. The link above was migrated from the old Connect Site to Uservoice and is a decade old. Different versions of the cardinality estimator can change the execution plan which may be why you are just hitting the issue now

Comment: As you say you are still hitting the issue with `TRY` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61782738/73226