# String or binary data would be truncated: Error not caught by TRY_CAST

Tags: sql-server

The query below...

```
SELECT YEAR(TRY_CAST(m.MetaValue AS DATE))
FROM MetaData m
```

...results in this error:

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

If I filter the query to a valid recordset, the error goes away:

```
SELECT YEAR(TRY_CAST(m.MetaValue AS DATE))
FROM MetaData m
WHERE m.MetaKey IN (...)
```

If I try to filter based on the selected expression, the query fails again:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(TRY_CAST(m.MetaValue AS DATE)) AS Yr
    FROM MetaData m
    WHERE MetaKey IN (...)
) x
WHERE x.Yr > 1900
```

What's going on here? I get the sense that SQL Server is optimizing the query into something along these lines, but I don't know how to prevent it:

```
SELECT YEAR(TRY_CAST(m.MetaValue AS DATE)) AS Yr
FROM MetaData m
WHERE MetaKey IN (...)
AND YEAR(TRY_CAST(m.MetaValue AS DATE)) > 1900
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this issue if `MetaValue` is `> 8,000` bytes. It throws an error not caught by the  `TRY_CAST`.

A simple demo of this is below ([db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4552c1c469efa8b102cfd71c912abc79))

```
DECLARE @X NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'X'
SET @X = REPLICATE(@X, 4001)

SELECT TRY_CAST(@X AS DATE)
```

In general SQL Server can evaluate expressions [out of logical processing order](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) causing the potential for this even if all the ones matching the `WHERE MetaKey IN (...)` condition are short strings (also warned about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)).

Guarding the `TRY_CAST` in an additional `CASE` expression should resolve things in this case

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(m.MetaValue) <8000 THEN YEAR(TRY_CAST(m.MetaValue AS DATE)) END
FROM MetaData m
WHERE m.MetaKey IN (...)
```

Comment: Good insight. I had assumed that TRY_CAST would catch any error. There are indeed values with length > 8000 in the table, and this eliminates the error.

Comment: @nw. I would say that this is a bug and `TRY_CAST` should suppress the error here